# Mention of Valmiki installing the Saraswathi idol in Brahmanda Purana

Tags: ramayana, saraswati, idols, valmiki, brahmanda-purana

The following excerpt is taken from the [puranic story](https://www.basaratemple.org/basaratemple.php) of Basara Gnana Saraswathi temple

> ఆది కవి వాల్మికి ఇక్కడ సరస్వతీ దేవిని ప్రతిష్టించి రామాయణం వ్రాసాడని
> బ్రహ్మాండ పురాణం వివరిస్తుంది.
>
> Brahmanda Purana describes that the first poet Valmiki installed
> Saraswathi Devi here and wrote Ramayana

The place mentioned in the excerpt is Basara, which was formerly known as Vyasapuri or Vyasara.

Which chapter of Brahmanda Purana mentions that Valmiki wrote Ramayana after installing Saraswathi Devi in Basara?